# how to allow non root user to create tun devices

Tags: networking, network-interface, udev

I am developing a program which requires opening `/dev/net/tun` and issuing `ioctl()` on it but without root user I get permission denied. I think proper udev rules can help solve this issue. I tried creating a new udev rule in the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/my_net_tun.rules` with the rule `KERNEL=="tun", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="static_node=net/tun"` and then reloaded the udev rules but still I get permission denied. I think something might be wrong with my rule. How can I fix this?

Comment: The right way would be to integrate with NetworkManager, or at least run a root-level daemon that opens tunnels on behalf of user-level clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not enough. Even if a process is able to open `/dev/net/tun`, it should also have the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability in order to create new tun/tap devices, or assign an owner to them.

This is explained in the [`tuntap.rst`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/tuntap.rst) file from the kernel documentation.

Comment: All what's needed should be described here (including how the normal user can then open the existing interface): https://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/

Comment: That document is exactly everything I need. Fantastic

Comment: link in answer is dead

Comment: @Ariaan fixed, thanks